# Regex replace all words with given character numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have text, for exp: `Test numbers test count gggg aaaaaa`

I need replace all words with count of characters 4(or other number) to "`SUPER`".
What is the easiest way to do it?

Now I tried to do something this, but it not work properly:

```
String pattern = "[aA-zZ]+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myText);
    while (m.find()) {
        String word = myText.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        System.out.println("one word |" + word + "|");
        if (m.end() - m.start() == myWord.length) {
            m.replaceAll("SUPER");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `\b[^\s]{4}\b` [Link](https://regex101.com/r/TTPhuz/2)

Comment: See my answer below to make sure you only replace 4-*letter* words, and not numbers. Please feel free to drop a comment if you need more help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern : `\b\w{4}\b` a for-letter group with a word boundary at start and at end

```
public static String rplcWordWithSize(int size, String sentence) {
    return sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{" + size + "}\\b", "SUPER");
}
```

Example of use :

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String str = "Test numbers test count gggg aaaaaa";
    System.out.println(rplcWordWithSize(3, str));  //Test numbers test count gggg aaaaaa
    System.out.println(rplcWordWithSize(4, str));  //SUPER numbers SUPER count SUPER aaaaaa
    System.out.println(rplcWordWithSize(5, str));  //Test numbers test SUPER gggg aaaaaa
}
```

Comment: [Same comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469954/3832970) apply here.

Answer (score 3):

`str.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "SUPER");` should work, `\\w` means word character; `\\b` means word boundary

Comment: This is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: `\w` matches also `[0-9]` and `_`. They want to match letters only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works with unicode strings of exact 4 characters. I tried with  `"\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C".replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "SUPER");` and it worked.

Comment: @procrastinator If you do not believe me, [here is a demo](https://ideone.com/Fthn0m). And `"\\b\\w{4}\\b"` does not replace neither `Маша` nor `кашу`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`[aA-zZ]+` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970), as the `A-z` range matches `` [, \, ], ^, _, ` `` beside the English letters.

If you do not expect to replace "words" like `1234` or `wrd5`, and just want to replace *natural language* non-compound words, use either of the two solutions below.

This one is Unicode-aware, `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letters and `\b` (a word boundary) "supports" Unicode word boundaries thanks to the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier embedded flag, `(?U)`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)\\b\\p{L}{4}\\b", "SUPER");
```

Or, if you only plan to work with ASCII:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b[a-zA-Z]{4}\\b", "SUPER");
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/fAo7vK):

```
System.out.println("Test numbers test count gggg aaaaaa".replaceAll("\\b[a-zA-Z]{4}\\b", "SUPER"));
// => SUPER numbers SUPER count SUPER aaaaaa
System.out.println("Маша ела кашу".replaceAll("(?U)\\b\\p{L}{4}\\b", "SUPER")); 
// => SUPER ела SUPER
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(myText);
String word = myText.substring(m.start(), m.end());

String[] words = word.Split(" ");
String newword = "";
for(String w : words){
if(w.length == myWord.length){
newword += "SUPER ";
}
else{
newword += w + " ";
}
}
Console.println(newword);
```

Did this straight out of the texteditor so there could be some minor errors.